# Get numbers after a specific character C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string containing this text...

```
1. G66I11.J270.P5.C90.(+K2H1+)
2. G66I11.J90.P-5.(+K2H1+)
3. G66I215.4J270.P-55.Q-6.T2531(+K2H1+)
...
```

I need to extract the value after character "P" is 5 or 55.

Now I'm using IndexOf to get:

```
int indexP = 0;
int number;
if (lines.Contains("P-"))
{
     indexP = lines.IndexOf("P-") + 1;
}
else if (lines.Contains("P") && !lines.Contains("P-"))
{
     indexP = lines.IndexOf("P");
}
if (lines.Contains("Q"))
{
    int indexQ = 0;
    if (lines.Contains(".Q"))
    {
         indexQ = lines.IndexOf(".Q");
    }

    if (indexQ > indexP)
    {
          number = Int.Parse(lines.Substring(indexP + 1, indexQ - indexP - 1));
    }
}

if (lines.Contains("C"))
{
    int indexC = 0;
    if (lines.Contains(".C"))
    {
         indexC = lines.IndexOf(".C");
    }

    if (indexC > indexP)
    {
          number = Int.Parse(lines.Substring(indexP + 1, indexC- indexP - 1));
    }
}
...
```

I returned exactly but after "P" character can be any character.

So if do it this way it will be very long code :(

i want to find a shorter way. Can you show me how to do something?
Thanks.

Comment: What would be the expected results in your example? 5, -5, -55? or 5, 5, 55? Could there be strings without "P"? Or with multiple "P"? Or with "P" not followed by digits?

Comment: @KlausGütter expected results is 5,5,55. Always have "P" and after "P" alway have digits . Couldn't there be strings without "P" or couldn't there string with multiple "P"

Comment: This is not a complete description of what constitutes valid text or invalid text.  I don't think you've described enough to tell me how to validate any arbitrary string.  I can make all kinds of assumptions.  It looks like there are fields separated by `.` characters, like text.Split('.') might be a good start.  Then you might want to find the substring that StartsWith `P`.  It sure looks like `.P-5.` is supposed to extract a `-5` and `.P5.` is supposed to extract a `5`.  But I'm just guessing.  You should clarify all these details in your question.  Is `P3.14` supposed to return `3.14`?

Comment: Is `lines` supposed to be an array of strings or is it a single string containing newlines?  Should we be splitting by newline first?

Comment: sorry for not being specific. it's a separate line , not array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pattern to match P followed by an optional `-` and then capture the numbers 0-9 in a group.

```
P-?([0-9]+)
```

- `P-?` Match `P` and optional `-`
- `([0-9]+)` Capture 1 or more digits 0-9 in group 1

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=P-%3f%28%5b0-9%5d%2b%29&i=1.+G66I11.J270.P5.C90.%28%2bK2H1%2b%29%0d%0a2.+G66I11.J90.P-5.%28%2bK2H1%2b%29%0d%0a3.+G66I215.4J270.P-55.Q-6.T2531%28%2bK2H1%2b%29%0d%0aG98X30.Y292.5I87.75J18.5P5K6) *(click on the table tab)* and a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/Cf87VT).

For example

```
string pattern = @"P-?([0-9]+)";
string s = @"1. G66I11.J270.P5.C90.(+K2H1+)
2. G66I11.J90.P-5.(+K2H1+)
3. G66I215.4J270.P-55.Q-6.T2531(+K2H1+)
G98X30.Y292.5I87.75J18.5P5K6";
var numbers = Regex.Matches(s, pattern)
           .Select(i => int.Parse(i.Groups[1].Value))
           .ToArray();
Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", numbers));
```

Output

```
[5, 5, 55, 5]
```

Comment: your regex is doesn't match with "G98X30.Y292.5I87.75J18.5P5K6

Comment: @dev.for.live I have updated the answer, in that case you don't need the word boundaries.

Comment: yessss, that's what i need . Thank you very much . I will put it as the answer

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `Regex` and match expression. Something like this,

```
// Example input
List<string> input = new List<string>();
input.Add("G66I11.J270.P5.C90.(+K2H1+)");
input.Add("G66I11.J90.P-5.(+K2H1+)");
input.Add("G66I215.4J270.P-55.Q-6.T2531(+K2H1+)");
input.Add("G66I11.J90.X-5.(+K2H1+)");

Regex match = new Regex(@"(?<=P)-*\d+(?=.)");
var values = input.Select(x => match.Match(x)?.Value).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList();

// values =
Count = 3
    [0]: "5"
    [1]: "-5"
    [2]: "-55"
```

`Regex(@"(?<=P)-*\d+(?=.)");` -> this checks for `P` from the start.. and after finding it, it takes 0 or more `-` .. takes the number (\d+) until there is a `.`.

Only caveat to this is.. it only selects the first match. If you want multiple matches, switch the `match.Match` to `match.Matches` method which gives you a list of values. you'll have to update the Select statement to return all values.

Comment: But i want to get
 Count = 3
    [0]: "5"
    [1]: "5"
    [2]: "55"
How I should edit the regex ?

Comment: It's interesting that in your code you used a List<string> but in the question's code it looks like `lines` is supposed to be a single string, with the _lines_ presumably separated by new line characters.  It would be awesome if the original question were more clear about this.

Comment: `values.Count` will give you the number

Comment: "G98X30.Y292.5I87.75J18.5P5" doesn't match . I add * in the final your regex and work well now . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this - assuming your 'lines' is a multi-line string like so.

```cs
string lines = @"
1. G66I11.J270.P5.C90.(+K2H1+)
2. G66I11.J90.P-5.(+K2H1+)
3. G66I215.4J270.P-55.Q-6.T2531(+K2H1+)
";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^P]*P-?([^\.]+)\.");

var matches = regex.Matches(lines);
Console.WriteLine($"Count: {matches.Count}");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{match.Groups[1].Value}");
}

// Count: 3
// 5
// 5
// 55
```

For a single line:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^P]*P-?([^\.]+)\.");

string line = "1. G66I11.J270.P5.C90.(+K2H1+)";
var match = regex.Match(line);
Console.WriteLine($"{match.Groups[1].Value}");
// 5
```

Comment: I just tested it on string : G66I11.J270.P5.C90.(+K2H1+).  But get this error : https://prnt.sc/20lkx9u

Comment: But you're not using the code (regex string) I gave you.  In your image it shows you're using your own invalid string for the RegEx.

Comment: But i'm need regex for per separate line . example : Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^P]*P-?([^\.]+)\.");
                        Pnumber = regex.Match(lines[i]).Value; But I'm not good at regex to fix them

Comment: You're also not grabbing the correct value from the match. In this answer -- you still need to get `.Groups[1].Value` not just `.Value`

Comment: but lines[i] is a string , not array . can u fix it to use on string not array ? I'm not good at regex to fix them

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix it. I'm showing you that it is a string.  In your example you have `lines` and it's a string.  I have `lines` and it's a string.  Now you want to have `lines` as an array with `lines[i]` as a string?

Comment: your regex is doesn't match with "G98X30.Y292.5I87.75J18.5P5K6"